# Request body has invalid json format - Python

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to post JSON data (RESTful API) using python.

```
    null = none
    payload = {
    "priority": 1,
    "hello_id": 207,
    "bye_id": 207,
    "s1": 1,
    "s2": 2,
    "sub": "CHECK 123",
    "t1": "Leave",
    "product_id": null,
    "due": "2001-01-01T06:11:54.884Z",
    "tags": [
    "HelloTag"
    ]
    }

    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(myurl, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    (OR)
    r = requests.post(myurl, json = json.dumps(payload_post), headers=headers)
    (OR)
    r = requests.post(myurl, data = payload_post, headers=headers, auth=(username_accadmin, password_accadmin))
    (OR)
    r = requests.post(myurl, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

None of the above 3 lines seems to yield the expected response (or) the response that I get in Postman.

```
    In the response I get : 
    "Validation failed","errors":[{"field":"priority","message":"Unexpected/invalid field in request","code":"invalid_field"}] 
    (FOR ALL FIELDS IN THE JSON DATA)
```

Why is the data wrong even when I convert the dict() to JSON using dumps() method?

NOTE : If all the fields in the payload were string, the data is posted as expected.

Comment: Is your payload supposed to be embedded in some larger object that the API is expecting?

Comment: I gave the same payload in POSTMAN. It's working as expected.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil Ultimately, the data *must* be a string; that's the only thing HTTP can accept. `requests` simply encodes non-string values for you.

Comment: @DeathJack2.0 What is `none`?

Comment: @chepner I was talking about the `data` argument in `requests.post`. Unsure if you pass a string it will send it as intended, unlike a dict / list.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, null cannot be recognized by python, so none is assigned to null before referencing it in the payload.

Comment: @chepner Yeah, thanks. I realized that after testing the code. `json` is the argument I meant, not `data`.

Comment: Please review the edited code. Either of the 3 lines seems to work.

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil I tried, If it had worked I would have accepted the answer. I get 'Validation failed' for all fields as the response.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`data` should be a `dict` or `list`, not a string (which the `dumps`) returns.

```
r = requests.post(myurl, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

See the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#make-a-request). Also, you should use `None` instead of `null` in your payload.